# quotes in php array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pass a php array to javascript. I've tried several examples taken form this site, but the rest of my code seem not to recognize them. I think the problem is in the quotes or format of the array.

First: var functionlist defined as below works OK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var functionlist = Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12');
    //Rest of the code
</script>
```

Second: var functionlist defined as below works OK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var functionlist=Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    //Rest of the code
</script>
```

But the code below is not working, despite the fact that echoing $TransfArray renders something quite similar to the above.

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $OriginalArray[$i] = $i;
    }
    $TransfArray= "'" . implode("','", $OriginalArray) . "'";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var functionlist = Array(<? echo $TransfArray; ?>);
    //Rest of the code
</script>
```

Nor does the code below

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $OriginalArray[$i] = $i;
    }
    $Original_to_json = json_encode($OriginalArray);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var functionlist =  <?php echo $Original_to_json; ?>;
    //Rest of the code
</script>
```

Does anyone detect the problem?
Thnaks in advance.

Comment: How does your original php array look like and how would you like it to look in javascript? json_encode really should do the trick nicely.

Comment: What does the second example output to the browser?

Comment: What does the output of those PHP examples give? i.e. How does it differ to what works? Ideally, you want the output to be: `var functionlist = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];` and without the quotes if you want to deal with numbers in JavaScript.

Comment: Since i'm rather newbie, i'm just trying to run the code above. But can't pass $OriginalArray defined in php (numbers from 1 to 12) to var functionlist.

Comment: Show us the Javascript that is using the array. The array gets created properly, so your Javascript must be at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use casting as follows,

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
$OriginalArray[]= (String)$i;
}
$Original_to_json=json_encode($OriginalArray);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var functionlist =  <?php echo $Original_to_json; ?>;
//Rest of the code
</script>
```

Comment: Why? He shows no code that requires the values of the Javascript array to be a string rather than an int.

Comment: @Crush user1726522 is almost reached his goal, i guess he may need some text as an identifier.

Comment: He might be treating it as a String, but Javascript should automatically transform it into a String in almost any instance he is using it. Unfortunately, we have no idea what the OP is doing with the array.

Comment: Wow! So many responses in minutes! Thanks to all of you guys.
The rest of the code is rather complicated, and I don't understand it completely. Is a modified version to autocomplete a combobox taken from http://www.somacon.com/p241.php. In that site, the list is "manually" defined, whereas I wanted to load from a database.

Adding a (String) as suggested by hilarudeens when defining $OriginalArray do the trick.

Again, thanks a lot!

PS: I should have asked before. I was searching for the problem for one and a half days. You solved it in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Writing JavaScript code with PHP is a terrible practice. You shouldn't be doing that. Instead, you can do something different and easy.

1. In PHP, you generate a JSON document by converting the array to a JSON object. Use the json_encode function for that. Name your file "json.php" (though naming is data.json is probably a better practice, but you'll have to go through more steps).
2. Now, you can include the file with in your HTML document 
   `<script src="json.php"></script>` Or you can use AJAX to load it dynamically.
3. The JSON object will have the JavaScript array.

Comment: @crush My suggestion is not about using json_encode or another function. It's about "not mixing" PHP with JavaScript. You should keep the front-end and back-end separate.

Comment: Then this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var functionlist =  <?php echo json_encode($OriginalArray); ?>;
//Rest of the code
</script>
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: What did you do differently? Nothing.