# Uncaught Syntax Error with Javascript and Php Strings

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, string, syntax-error

I have a php webpage that displays a calendar with specific dates displayed on it.

The dates are stored in a MySql database.

At the beginning of the webpage, I do the following:

```
<?php
//Load in database

$query = "SELECT ID, Full_Name, Arrival_Date, Departure_Date FROM bookings ORDER BY Arrival_Date";

if ($result = $dbc->query($query))       //Retrieve all the booking details
{
    $numrows = $result-> num_rows;

    $id_array;
    $name_array;
    $arrival_array;
    $departure_array;

    for ($count = 0; $count < $numrows; $count++)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $id_array[$count] = $row['ID'];
        $name_array[$count] = $row['Full_Name'];
        $arrival_array[$count] = $row['Arrival_Date'];
        $departure_array[$count] = strval($row['Departure_Date']);
    }
}
else
{
    //Error
}
?>
```

ID is a number
Full_Name is a string
Arrival_Date and Departure_Date are dates (YYYY-MM-DD)

The calendar is a javascript object therefore I need to get the booking information into my javascript function to be able to use it.

This is how I am trying to do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array_ID = [<?php echo implode(",",$id_array); ?>];
    var array_name = [<?php echo implode(",",$name_array); ?>];
    var array_arrival = [<?php echo implode(",",$arrival_array); ?>];                                           
    var array_departure = [<?php echo implode(",",$departure_array); ?>]; 

    var booking_numbers = <?php echo $numrows; ?>;
</script>
```

However, I am getting an error **'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier'** on the line:

```
var array_name = [<?php echo implode(",",$name_array); ?>];
```

I suspect this is because some of the names have spaces in as the array is coming up as

```
var array_name = [Pippa,Pippa Smith,Pippa Smith];
```

When the php values are put in.

So here's my question. How can I tell javascript to treat those inputs as a string.

And I'm aware this might be a terrible way of combining javascript and php, so if anyone has any better suggestions, I'll happily take them!

Comment: Please show us the generated js code. If the values in `$name_array` are strings, you're at least missing quotes around them.

Comment: @Pippa Rose Smith, Can you look following URL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090128/quotes-in-php-array-to-javascript-array/15090285#15090285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) one way around is using `implode` in php and spliting it in javasciript using `split`..

best way though is to use `echo json_encode($id_array)` in php  so that it converts the array into javascript object

Comment: Upvoted, `json_encode` is the way to go here. You're asking for a world of hurt to try to encode strings from PHP into JavaScript objects any other way, given that the functionality is already a) available easily and b) well tested.

Comment: Ok, so do you mean var array_ID = [<?php echo json_encode($id_array); ?>];

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark string literals for javascript by putting them between quotes.

```
var array_name = ["Pippa","Pippa Smith","Pippa Smith"];
```

Use [json_encode()](http://docs.php.net/json_encode) to get a valid javascript object literal from your php value(s).

---

on a side-note: why do you change the structure of the data from

```
[1] x y z
[2] X Y Z
```

to

```
 [1]  [2]
  x    X
  y    Y
  z    Z
```

i.e. why do you have those separate variables `array_ID, array_name, array_arrival, array_departure` instead of one array holding all the information?